# NextJS cookies are set on localhost but not on production

Tags: cookies, next.js, session-cookies

I'm trying to set an encrypted cookie, so that I can use it later to mitigate CSRF attacks. I'm using [Cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies) module to set the cookie.

It is working fine on localhost and the cookie 'xcsrf' is created. But on production, it's not being created.

```
import Cookies from 'cookies';
import { NextPage, GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { encryptWithAES } from '@utils/tokenEncryption';
import { wrapper } from 'store';


const LoginPage: NextPage = () => <div> Login page </div>


export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  async (ctx) => {
    const { store, req, res } = ctx;
    const props = await getPageProps(store);
    const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
    const token = `${Date.now()}`; // I know this is not the best way. I'm just testing
    const encrypted = encryptWithAES(token);
    cookies.set('xcsrf',encrypted, {
      httpOnly: true,
    });
    return {
      props: {...props },
    };
  },
);
```

utils/tokenEncryption

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

export const encryptWithAES = (text: string | CryptoJS.lib.WordArray) => {
    const passphrase = process.env.CSRF_SECRET as string;
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, passphrase).toString();
  };
```

I have checked other questions on StackOverflow but I couldn't find a solution.